# How to raise warning with __future__ instead of exception

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

Can I import the `__future__` module of Python-2.7 and raise a warning instead of an exception?

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Raises a syntax error. I prefer a warning

Comment: Seems there is no way to do this.  I would have expected `python -Wall -3` to print a warning for this, but since it's a *syntax* change it's too late in the warning machinery.

Comment: i don't see why the above would raise an error.